# Using XText to create a DSL for describing proprietary XML-formats

Tags: dsl, dsl-tools, xtext

At the moment, I have to work with [XACML](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml#CURRENT). As there doesn't seem to be an editor to fit my needs, and as writing documents in it is a real pain, I wonder if I could not create some sort of DSL to make creating documents easier (are less error-prone). Is this possible with XText? I have a feeling it's possible but quite hard to do (especially for someone who doesn't know XText ;-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of manually edited XML files is a typical use case for Xtext. The tedious part is the syntax definition itself. As soon as you have an idea how your files should look like, it's usually straight forward to get a working prototype with Xtext. What sort of concerns do you have?